# Accessing a windows truecrypt volume using ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, truecrypt, livecd

I have a serious problem here: My computer does not boot any more (hangs on the windows start screen), so I tried to use a Ubuntu Live CD access the files and scan for root kits, or at least back up everything.

However, this is not as easy as it sounds, because I have two major setup specialities:

1. My computer is a Sony VPC Z13 with 3 64GB SSD disks that are in a [fake raid](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto)
2. My windows volume is encrypted using TrueCrypt

I have created a bootable Ubuntu usb drive which recognizes the raid by default:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/dev$ sudo dmraid -ay
RAID set "isw_bibiifejd_Volume0" already active
RAID set "isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p1" already active
RAID set "isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p2" already active
RAID set "isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3" already active
```

`isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p1` is an 8GB windows restore partition. I can mount this easily with `mount /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p1 /mnt/win1`. 
`isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p2` is a 100M partition called "System Reserved" and was mounted automatically by ubuntu. I think this is the place of the bootloader (?).
`isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p2` is my windows partition, encrypted with true crypt. fdisk says the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/dev$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3: 183.6 GB, 183617154048 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 22323 cylinders, total 358627254 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 393216 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3ec32997

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I was trying to mount `isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3` with truecrypt, but I get an error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/dev$ sudo truecrypt -t /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3 /mnt/win3
Enter password for /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3: 
Enter keyfile [none]: 
Protect hidden volume (if any)? (y=Yes/n=No) [No]: 
Incorrect password or not a TrueCrypt volume.
```

Then I tried this command, as my partition is a fully encrypted partition:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ truecrypt -t --mount-options=system
>   /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3 /mnt/win3  Enter password for
>   /dev/mapper/isw_bibiifejd_Volume0p3:  Enter keyfile [none]:  Protect
>   hidden volume (if any)? (y=Yes/n=No) [No]:  Error: Partition device
>   require

What does this mean? Google does not know anything about it.

Is my approach to mount the true crypt volume correct? Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried mounting it using the TrueCrypt GUI? Maybe it gives better error messages?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to restore the volume using a Windows PE (preinstalled environment). It is important to notice that using TrueCrypt 64 bit in the PE was impossible for me due to a bug. But 32bit version worked fine.